# How to send the KeyEvent in Robo Script?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-test-lab

I was using the Android Studio's Robo Test Recorder of Firebase Test Lab.

I was trying to record the action of send keyCode. ex. `KeyEvent.KeyCode.DPAD_UP`.

Is there any way to record it?

Please advice me, if you know.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recording of specific key codes is not implemented in Roboscript Recorder yet, but there is a recent feature request for that.